# get selected item's data in listview fetched from json

Tags: android, json, listview

I want to send the data of selected item in a listview to the next activity.This data has been fetched from JSON.
But it is returning last object's data of json and not that of the item i am selecting.Please help me to get the data of selected item that is fetched from json and pass it on to next activity using bundle.

```
String savedPlaceAddressLine1,savedPlaceAddressLine2,savedPlaceCity,savedPlaceZip,savedPlaceState,savedPlaceCountry,savedPlaceLat,savedPlaceLong;

 class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
....

JSONObject object2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(2);
                        JSONArray jsonArraySavedPlaces = object2.getJSONArray("saved-places");
                            Log.i("Status2", "GotInnerArray");
                            for (int j = 0; j < jsonArraySavedPlaces.length(); j++)
                            {

                                JSONObject object4 = jsonArraySavedPlaces.getJSONObject(j);

                                ListItemDataSource listItemDataSource= new ListItemDataSource();

                                JSONObject addressObject=object4.getJSONObject("address");
                                Log.i("Status", "GotAddressesArray");

                                savedPlaceAddressLine1=addressObject.getString("address-line1");Log.i("Status1", savedPlaceAddressLine1);
                                savedPlaceAddressLine2=addressObject.getString("address-line2");Log.i("Status1", savedPlaceAddressLine2);
                                savedPlaceCity=addressObject.getString("city");Log.i("Status1", savedPlaceCity);
                                savedPlaceZip=addressObject.getString("zip");Log.i("Status1", savedPlaceZip);
                                savedPlaceState=addressObject.getString("state");Log.i("Status1", savedPlaceState);
                                savedPlaceCountry=addressObject.getString("country");Log.i("Status1", savedPlaceCountry);
                                savedPlaceTitle=addressObject.getString("address-title");Log.i("Status1", savedPlaceTitle);
                                savedPlaceLat=addressObject.getString("lattitude");Log.i("Status1", savedPlaceLat);
                                savedPlaceLong=addressObject.getString("longitude");Log.i("Status1", savedPlaceLong);

                                String placeAddress=savedPlaceAddressLine1+","+savedPlaceAddressLine2+","+savedPlaceCity+","+savedPlaceState+","+savedPlaceCountry;
                                listItemDataSource.setPlaceTitle(savedPlaceTitle);Log.i("Status2", "Title");
                                listItemDataSource.setPlaceAddress(placeAddress);Log.i("Status2", "Address");

                                itemsList.add(listItemDataSource);
                                Log.i("info","got data of object"+j);
                            }
                }
                return true;

        }
```

...
}

in OnCreate:

```
                     Bundle extras=new Bundle();

                                                extras.putString("savedPlacesAddress-title", savedPlaceTitle);
                                                extras.putString("savedPlacesAddress1", savedPlaceAddressLine1);
                                                extras.putString("savedPlacesAddress2", savedPlaceAddressLine2);
                                                extras.putString("savedPlacesCity", savedPlaceCity);
                                                extras.putString("savedPlacesZip", savedPlaceZip);
                                                extras.putString("savedPlacesState", savedPlaceState);
                                                extras.putString("savedPlacesCountry", savedPlaceCountry);

                                        String data=savedPlaceAddressLine1+","+savedPlaceAddressLine2+","+savedPlaceCity+","+savedPlaceZip+","+savedPlaceState+","+savedPlaceCountry;
                                        Log.d("data",data);
                                        intent.putExtras(extras);

                                        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a model class AppAddress.
2. Create all setter and getter method for your property like address1, address2, zip code etc.
3. implement this class by Serializable.
4. Create a Array list with AppAddress type.
5. Add all data in your AppAddress class by setter method and add it into arraylist.
6. When you will click on row of listview then pass object of AppAddress class by bundle.
7. Receive this object from other activity.

You can download sample code from below link:

1. http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/
2. http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/
3. http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-json-parsing-with-jsonobject-and-loading-to-listview-example/

Comment: if its helpful then please hit as right answer for other.