# Best way to process a huge HTTP JSON response

Tags: java, android, json, performance, inputstream

What is the most efficient way to parse a JSON reply from a server that is return as 1 huge line?
I don’t want/need to “map” this JSON to some custom/business objects as I need only specific parts of the structure.
Mainly finding a specific tag and its values among a set of arrays.

**UPDATE:**

I am looking for an efficient way to parse an JSON response from an internal server.
The response is sent as a huge single line. The file is so big that trying to understand the structure using brower’s json plugin was still difficult as the browser was “stuck”.
For my needs I want specific bits of information and do not want to map the JSON to actual business object/classes as it will be too much unneeded work.
What I currently do for testing this out (I have removed exception handling for clarity):

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse response = null;
response = client.execute(httpGet);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
StringBuilder builder = null;
if (statusCode == 200) {
          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
          InputStream content = entity.getContent();
          builder = new StringBuilder();
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
          String line;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
          }
          if ( builder.length() != 0 ) {
                processJSON(builder.toString());
          }
           return builder.toString();
}

private void processJSON(String s) {
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(s);
        String url = (String) o.get("url");

       JSONArray array = o.getJSONArray("individualroles");

       for( int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++ ) {
                JSONObject elem = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                String fullNameForDisplay = (String) elem.get("fullName");
                String status =  (String) elem.get("status");
                String date = (String) elem.get("date");
                String fullDescription = (String) elem.get("full_description").toString();
                JSONArray contacts = (JSONArray) elem.get("contacts");
                for(int j = 0; j < contacts.length(); j ++ ) {
                    JSONObject contact = (JSONObject) contacts.get(j);
                    String contactName = contact.getString("contactName");
                    String displayName = contact.getString("displayName");
                    String realAddress = contact.getString("realAddress");

                    Log.i(“MyApp”, “contactName = “ + contactName + “ displayName = “ + displayName + “ readAddress  = “ + realAddress);
                }
         }
```

This literally fluds the log as the JSON response i.e. the `String s` has length of ~7Million characters.
Also I see in the log many statements like:

I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 389(14KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(851KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 30.651ms total 77.127ms

For testing this what I did is that in the fragment’s `onCreate` I do:

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(“MyApp”, (new JSONParser().get(JSON_URL_SERVER)));
               }
        });
        thread.start();
```

Is there any issue e.g. with memory and GC with this approach? How can I improve this?

Comment: You can use Jackson and its streaming API, for instance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29272990/get-selected-items-data-in-listview-fetched-from-json/29273258#29273258

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: Can you show the JSON and the part you are interested in?

Comment: @Ridcully:I'll post how I am trying to do it as soon as possible to give more info

Comment: @Ridcully:Check updated OP please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something that parses the inputstream during reading.

Similar to SAX parsers for XML there are such implementations for JSON too. There's Jackson for one and alsp [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) which has a quite simple approach to it, [expained here](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples#Example_5_-_Stoppable_SAX-like_content_handler).

If I understand your code right, you are mainly looking for everything under key `"individualroles"`. So with this SAX-like parser you'd implement a `ContentFinder` like the `KeyFinder` in the example and that is invoked by the Parser as soon as the required key is reached in the inputstream. Now you can handle that part of the JSON and then you can end the parsing/reading alltogether.

I'm sorry I cannot provide a more detailed explanation but I haven't used that particular library myself, it's just knowledge from SAX-parsers mapped to JSON I can provide.

Comment: `parses the input stream during reading` could you please elaborate on that part? My understanding is that the inputstream is the whole response already donwloaded from the server. Is that not the case?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on how the server sends the data. However, independently of that, there is no need for you to read the whole data from the inputstream and build a huge string from it and then parse it all. Using this ContentFinder approach is as fast as you can get and it is also does not require much memory (so no GC problems) as the data you are not interested in are not kept around in memory.

Comment: Could I use the SAX approach with volley?

Comment: Sure you could, but as far as I've seen they first read all the response and invoke the `onResponse()` method with the whole string. Perhaps you can overcome that with a custom request but I didn't find that at a quick glance.

Comment: I accept the answer but I did not use json simple. I followed this: http://pivotallabs.com/parsing-json-data-efficiently-on-android-jsonreader/

Comment: Thank you for the SAX suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to take some parts of the structure returned as response, you can do it manually:

```
try {
    // if response is a single object:
    JSONObject obe = new JSONObject( response );
    int value = json.getInt( "tag" );
    // or if it is an array:
    JSONArray obes = new JSONArray( response );
    JSONObject obe = obes.getJSONObject( 0 );
} catch ( JSONException e ) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JsonParser` from [jackson-core](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core).

It provides api to read token by token from input stream.

Sample json

```json
{
    "employees" : [
        {
            "empNo":10001,
            "birthDate":"02 September 1953",
            "firstName":"Georgi",
            "lastName":"Facello",
            "gender":"M",
            "hireDate":"26 June 1986"
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Following are some cods with explanations for parsing above json response.

```java
// Create a parser from the response input stream
JsonParser jsonParser = objectMapper.getFactory().createParser(response.getBody());
    
    // Some condition checking, basically checking the response having `{`
    if(jsonParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
        // Checking the response having the field `"employees"`
        if(jsonParser.nextFieldName() == "employees") {
            // Checking the response having the token `[`
            if(jsonParser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
                // Loop until `]` found
                while(jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                    // Extract domain object
                    Employee employee = jsonParser.readValueAs(Employee.class);
                    // Do whatever with the domain object.
                }
            }
        }
    }

// Finally closing the parser.
jsonParser.close();
```

Above example is taken from [this blog post.](https://dev.to/ratulsharker/consume-large-json-response-in-spring-421j)